# Must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor c#

Tags: c#, .net, generic-type-parameters

Here is the my context class. I want to use my db takes the connection info from appsettings.json. I commented override method and added `public CoursesystemContext` but I got error.

```cs
namespace DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFreamwork.Contexts
{   
    public class CourseSystemContext : DbContext
    {
        public CourseSystemContext(DbContextOptions<CourseSystemContext>options): base(options)
        {

        }

        //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        //{
            // optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString: @"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=true");
            //optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString: @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=....;database=coursesystemdb");
        //}
    }
}
```

I added the json setting:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "connectionString": "server=localhost;userid=root;password=...;database=coursesystemdb"
}
```

and arranged `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<CourseSystemContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionString")));
```

Then I debug and get this error:

> Error CS0310  'CourseSystemContext' must be a non-abstract type with a
> public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter
> 'TContext' in the generic type or method
> 'EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity,
> TContext>'    DataAccess  C:\Users\kayha\Desktop\langsisv3-api-main\langsisv3-api-main\CourseSystem\DataAccess\Concrete\EntityFreamwork\EfAgencyDal.cs    14

How can solve this error? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `AddDbContext<T>()` method has a `new()` constraint on it, which requires that the type you use for the parameter be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor. Which, oddly enough, **is exactly what the error message says**. See duplicate for specifics about this generic constraint and its implications on types you use as the generic type parameter.

Comment: Your `EfEntityRepositoryBase` expects `new TContext()` to work. Perhaps it should receive a TContext as an argument from DI instead.

Comment: `public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IEntityRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
    where TContext : DbContext, new()`   Here is the EfEntityRepositoryBase class